# Error: unknown dialect

Tags: python-2.7, csv

I'm using the csv reader in the csv module to read a file in the format.

```
Filename, Foo, Label
```

Each record looks as follows.

```
file1.wav,"[  1.92849546e+02   2.86156126e+00  -7.96250116e+00 
7.29509485e+02   4.79000000e+02   5.51000000e+02]",1
```

I get the following error when reading the file.

```
set_ = csv.reader(open(foo), 'rb', delimiter = ',')
Error: unknown dialect
```

Also I am using python 2.7 on a windows machine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using the ***csv.reader*** api wrong

As per the documentation the 2nd argument to [csv.reader](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html#module-contents) is dialect  and "*rb*"  does not make sense.

Instead you probably intend to do something on these lines:

```
with open(foo) as input :
   reader = csv.reader(foo)
   #etc
```